# Why this Either-monad code does not type check?

Tags: haskell, monads, either

```
instance Monad (Either a) where
     return = Left
     fail = Right
     Left x >>= f = f x
     Right x >>= _ = Right x
```

this code frag in 'baby.hs' caused the horrible compilation error:

```
Prelude> :l baby
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( baby.hs, interpreted )

baby.hs:2:18:
Couldn't match expected type `a1' against inferred type `a'
  `a1' is a rigid type variable bound by
       the type signature for `return' at <no location info>
  `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
      the instance declaration at baby.hs:1:23
In the expression: Left
In the definition of `return': return = Left
In the instance declaration for `Monad (Either a)'

baby.hs:3:16:
Couldn't match expected type `[Char]' against inferred type `a1'
  `a1' is a rigid type variable bound by
       the type signature for `fail' at <no location info>
  Expected type: String
  Inferred type: a1
In the expression: Right
In the definition of `fail': fail = Right

baby.hs:4:26:
Couldn't match expected type `a1' against inferred type `a'
  `a1' is a rigid type variable bound by
       the type signature for `>>=' at <no location info>
  `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
      the instance declaration at baby.hs:1:23
In the first argument of `f', namely `x'
In the expression: f x
In the definition of `>>=': Left x >>= f = f x

baby.hs:5:31:
Couldn't match expected type `b' against inferred type `a'
  `b' is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for `>>=' at <no location info>
  `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
      the instance declaration at baby.hs:1:23
In the first argument of `Right', namely `x'
In the expression: Right x
In the definition of `>>=': Right x >>= _ = Right x
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

---

why this happen? and how could I make this code compile ?
thanks for any help~

i see. and i adjusted the code to see it compiles:

```
instance Monad (Either a) where
     return = Right
     Left a >>= f = Left a
     Right x >>= f = f x
```

it compiles successfully!
but...for a further more question:

```
instance Monad (Either a)
```

makes 'Either a' a monad and i got 'return = Right'...how could i get 'return = Left'?
i've tried this but failed:

```
instance Monad (`Either` a) where
     return = Left
     Right a >>= f = Right a
     Left x >>= f = f x
```

or:
    instance Monad (\x -> Either x a)

doesn't compile at all!

Comment: A blog post about this: http://ro-che.blogspot.com/2008/09/haskell-puzzle-either-monad.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. return should have type `forall b. b -> Either a b`, however Left has type `forall c. a -> Either a c`. You probably want Right here.
2. `fail` should have type `forall b. String -> Either a b`, however Right has type `forall b. b -> Either a b`, so if `b=String` that makes `String -> Either a String` which does not fit.
3. `>>=` should have type `Either a b -> (b -> Either a c) -> Either a c` however `Right x >>= _ = Right x` always returns a value of type `Either a b`, not `Either a c`.
4. `Left x >>= f = f x` does not work because x has type `a`, but `f` has type `b -> c`.

Answer (score 9):

Most of the confusion stems from the fact Left and Right are used backwards.  Considering only the type for return, its type from the Monad typeclass is as follows:

```
return :: (Monad m) => b -> m b
```

You're trying to define an instance for `m` = `Either a`, so return should have type:

```
return :: b -> Either a b
```

You're defining it as Left, which has type:

```
Left :: a -> Either a b
```

Note how the left hand side of the `->` differs.

Comment: i see. and i adjusted the code to see it compiles:

    instance Monad (Either a) where
         return = Right
         Left a >>= f = Left a
         Right x >>= f = f x

it compiles successfully!
but...for a further more question: 

    instance Monad (Either a)

makes 'Either a' a monad and i got 'return = Right'...how could i get 'return = Left'?
i've tried this but failed:

    instance Monad (`Either` a) where
         return = Left
         Right a >>= f = Right a
         Left x >>= f = f x

or:
    instance Monad (\x -> Either x a)

doesn't compile at all!

Comment: You can't make `Either a` a Monad with `return`=`Left`. A Haskell `Monad` is a typeclass of one parameter (let's take `b`), which matches the `return`'s argument's type.  This is incompatible with Haskell's definition of `Either`, which is a typeclass where the last argument is the one to the `Right`.  You could only achieve what you want by redefining `Either` with swapped type arguments, as in `data Either a b = Left b | Right a` but then you'd be incompatible with all the standard library's support on `Either` values.